# how to combine factors who predict different time-horizon?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am working on fleet management system these days, basically, I am trying to predict the usage 'y' of our fleet in a zip code in the future. We have some factors 'X', such as number of active users, number of active merchants etc.

If I can fix the time horizon, the problem will become relatively easy:

```
y = $\beta$X
```

However, there is no 'golden' time horizon. Practically, I need to predict every moment in the future.

Event worse, not all my factors are same. Some factors are strong in short term prediction, some factors are strong in long term prediction. If I force to combine them into one single regression model, I am afraid that I will be hurting the overall regression performance.

I was thinking about multi-target regression, but it does not really solve the problem. Multi-target regression might just give me an 'average (not in a statistical sense)' model that tries to predict multiple time-horizon, but due to each factor's predicting power, it might not predict well in any time horizon.

Does anyone has any insight for this?

Thanks!